# Insert the max date (independent from database)

Tags: java, date

In my local setup i'm using a simple H2 databse. The "hosted" solution will have another (similar but not same) database.

I need to insert the maximum possible date into a DateTime column. I tried to use

```
Instant.MAX
```

However this results in -169104626-12-11 20:08:15.99999999 in the column.

Is there a solid option on how to insert a maximum possible date?

Comment: What does `Instant.MIN` result in?

Comment: What shall be the symbolic meaning of such an instant? Infinite future?

Comment: Why don't you insert `31.12.9999 23:59:59`, which you can store as a constant in your java application?

Comment: Actually yes - infinit future , however not null - because it should be possible to easily filter later on using > now <

Comment: Maybe subtract 169104626 from INT MAX :D

Comment: I'm looking for a more general solution than simply inserting what I think is the maximum date - I like to use existing constants

Comment: They differ on different sql servers. MSSQL and DB2 for example use 9999 as maximum year but postgresql has 294276. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-datetime.html

Answer (score 4):

> max date (independent from database)

No such thing. Trying to set a maximum date is absolutely dependent on the database.

The topic of date-time handling is barely touched by the SQL standard (unfortunately). The data types and behavior for date-time vary *widely* amongst various databases. The minimum and maximum values can be radically different between various databases. Even within a single database, the min/max range of the various date-time data types can be dramatically different. For example, some databases have old proprietary date-time types as well as newer more common or standard types that behave quite differently.

Java itself has very different sets of date-time types:

- The troublesome legacy types (java.util & java.sql)
- The modern wisely-designed [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) types.

The min/max of these differ.

> Is there a solid option on how to insert a maximum possible date?

No.

If you are trying to use the maximum value as some kind of flag such as "undetermined future date" to avoid a NULL, instead choose some arbitrary date far enough in the future to exceed any legitimate value but not so far as to exceed the limits of any database you are possibly going to use. Define a constant for this value in your Java code and in your database, and document thoroughly.

I suggest sticking with a four-digit year to avoid all kinds of confusion and problems such as breaking reports & GUIs by exceeding the field’s width of display. Something like `9999`. Or perhaps `2666` because it is so noticeable to the human reader due to the [infamy of 666](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/666_%28number%29).

Search Stack Overflow for words such as Java, min, and max, for more discussion. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32593206/642706) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1743985/642706) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37138076/642706) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2393016/642706) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35149884/642706). This question is basically a duplicate of other Questions.